# get String from Preferences

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-preferences

I have EditText in preferences and I also have EditText in my layout.So I want to get string from Preferences and use it for EditText when i click my button.So i tried like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
}
//OnClick method
public void Button(View view) {
EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            String string = sharedPreferences
                    .getString("ime", "default");
            et1.setText(String.valueOf(string));
}
```

and my prefs xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <EditTextPreference android:title="Uredi Text"
        android:key="ime"
        android:summary="ime pjesme"

        />


</PreferenceScreen>
```

And Everytime when I click the button EditText text becomes "default"

Comment: What is the difference between this question and your last one?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `getBaseContext()` directly - use "local context", which in your case is Activity (as [activty extends Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)). So in your example code, replace it with `this`:

```
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences( this );
```

Comment: did you actually entered preferences and changed its value? is your preferences activity doing something beside loading res xml?

Comment: I only have edittext in preferences and i want to get the string from that edittext and use it in my layout..And yes i entered "test" in preferences and again in layout i get "default"